# SQLite 3 Database Open Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am having an odd problem opening my SQLite3 Database.

Scenario: User taps a row on a ListView, database opens, then it closes again successfully. No problems occur until the user taps to many times on the row, then the database fails to open. The function is called traditionally on the main thread, so only one process could happen, thus theoretically avoiding this issue.

Function Call:

```
[self openDB];
```

Obj-c Code:

```
-(void)OpenDataBase{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &sharedDataBase)!= SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(sharedDataBase);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
    }
}
```

It logs:

> Failed to open database
>
> There was an error accessing the database.  The error code is: 21

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**Edit** Here is the Error Printout: unable to open database file

Comment: Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to log the error.

Comment: BTW - don't call `sqlite3_close` on a database that failed to open. There's no point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", sqlite3_errmsg]); however it won't print out the number, it only prints out a "?" any ideas?

Comment: It needs to be: `NSLog(@"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sharedDataBase));`.

Comment: BTW - never use `stringWithFormat:` in an `NSLog` statement. The 1st parameter to `NSLog` is supposed to be format string so using `NSString stringWithFormat` is pointless.

Comment: Here is the printout:  Error: unable to open database file

Comment: Are you closing the database properly after each use? Be sure you aren't simply opening the database over and over without closing it each time.

Comment: How many instances of the db can be open at one time?

Comment: I don't know the limit. But you should always clean up what you use. FYI - in my own app I open the connection once and use it for the entire lifetime of my app. No need to open and close every time you need to do a query.

Comment: So if the app crashes without closing the db, will the data still be saved?

Comment: Yes. I've never had an issue with lost data even when the app crashes or is killed in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information from @rmaddy in the comments of the question, here is what worked for me:

I initialize the database, then open the database only once in the app. I have tested it, and even with a force close, it does not need to be closed.

Originally, the DB opened and closed every time I needed to access it, however, that is not necessary. Now that it is only open once, the app runs much faster.

Thank you @rmaddy for your input and suggestions.